# Validating Radio entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have 2 address entries on my form. I also have 2 radio buttons to designate the "preferred" mailing address.

I'm attempting to validate these 2 and am not really sure if I'm doing it correctly. It seems to work if I have both addresses filled but I can't seem to get it to validate correctly if one of the addresses isn't filled.

Here's the javascript that does the validation:

```
function checkMailingPrefs() {
    var prefs = ["MailPrefHome", "MailPrefBusi"];
    var field = ["HomeAddress1", "BusinessAddress1"];
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if ($("#"+prefs[i]).is(":checked") && $("#"+field[i]).val() == "") {
            $("#" + prefs[i]).prop('checked', false);
            $("#MailPrefBusi").validationEngine('showPrompt', 'You must select the correct Mailing Preference', 'error', true);
            return false;
        }
        if ($("#"+field[i]).val() == "" || !$("#"+prefs[i]).is(":checked")) {
            $("#MailPrefBusi").validationEngine({promptPosition : "bottomRight", scroll: true}).validationEngine('showPrompt', 'You must select the correct Mailing Preference', 'error',  true);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm using jQueryValidationEngine but it also doesn't correctly validate them. I only use it to show the validation error for these fields.

Here is the criteria:

If the MailPrefBusi is checked, then the BusinessAddress1 must be filled in.
If the MailPrefHome is checked, then the HomeAddress1 must be filled in.

If no MailPrefxxx is checked, show error. If no xxxAddress1 is filled, Show error.

Comment: You're explicitly validating `$("#MailPrefBusi").validationEngine` inside the loop.  Do you want to be validating the home address also?  e.g. `$("#"+field[i]).validationEngine` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your second if statement `if ($("#"+field[i]).val() == "" || !$("#"+prefs[i]).is(":checked")) {` is returning false when you don't want it to.  You should be able to accomplish what you want using this:

```
function checkMailingPrefs() {
    var prefs = ["MailPrefHome", "MailPrefBusi"];
    var field = ["HomeAddress1", "BusinessAddress1"];
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if ($("#"+prefs[i]).is(":checked") && $("#"+field[i]).val() == "") {
            // enhanced validation function call here
            return false;
        }
    }
    //if the user hasnt checked anything, you can remove this if the form should validate without the user having to set a radio button
    if(!$("#MailPrefBusi, #MailPrefHome").is(":checked")) {
      // enhanced validation function call here
      return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can see it working at this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/h0vj9r35/

Hope that helps!

Comment: While I have selected this, it is because i fond our working code. This one also has issues. It allows both radios to be selected.

Comment: @MB34 the browser will enforce only 1 radio button being selected provided the radio buttons are given the same name.  You can see what I'm talking about in the updated HTML at the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h0vj9r35/7/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't demonstrate that.

Comment: If you add a NAME attribute it fixes the issue, but it still doesn't allow none to be selected.

Comment: @MB34 You can allow none to be selected by removing the second `if` statement.  I clarified the comment in the answer so you can see which one to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out whether the corresponding fields are filled based on checkbox values in a scenario where you have n no. of checkboxes and fields and would like to avoid hardcoding of values, you may use the following:

```
var prefs = ["MailPrefHome", "MailPrefBusi"];
var field = ["HomeAddress1", "BusinessAddress1"];
var allEmpty = false;
var valueError = ""
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    if ($("#"+field[i]).val() == "" || !$("#"+prefs[i]).is(":checked")) {
        if(!$("#"+prefs[i]).is(":checked"))
          valueError += prefs[i] + "," ;
         else if($("#"+field[i]).val() == "")
          valueError += field[i];
        allEmpty = true;            
    }      

    if ($("#"+prefs[i]).is(":checked") && $("#"+field[i]).val() == "")
    {
        $("#" + prefs[i]).prop('checked', false);
        allEmpty = false;
        alert("Need to enter " + field[i]);
        return false;
    }      

    if((i == 1) && allEmpty)
    {
        alert("You need to select " + valueError);
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n0303qd6/1/

Comment: If none are selected, `Enter or Select values`, we do allow them to have none if both boxes are empty.

Comment: same issue `You need to select MailPrefHome,MailPrefBusi,`

Comment: Your questions says "If no MailPrefxxx is checked, show error. If no xxxAddress1 is filled, Show error." The provided fiddle correctly handles that. What exactly are you looking for ?